# Ocaml, syntax error but i don't know where, can somoene help me?

Tags: ocaml

This is my code, i need some help with it. Compiler give me some syntax error that i can't fix and i can't identify!

```
let n = read_int();  
    
    let schroder n = 
       let pointer = ref 0 in 
         for i = 1 to n-2 do
           pointer := !pointer + (schroder i * schroder n-i-1)
         done;
      schroder n = 3 * schroder n-1 + !pointer 
    !schroder n
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message including line number, column number.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your main problem is in the first line. The semicolon in OCaml is an operator with a left and right operand. This means that the semicolon on your first line will combine the expression before it (`read_int ()`) and the one after it (`let schroder ...`) into one expression. But when `let` occurs inside a larger expression, it requires an `in`. You don't have an `in` to match `let schroder ...`. That, I believe, is your syntax error.

If you want schroder to be defined at the outermost level (which I think you do), you should remove the semicolon on the first line.

When I make this change in your code, I no longer get a syntax error. Instead I get an error for which the compiler has a pretty good suggested fix.

There are still some more errors, but I hope this helps with the initial syntax error.